# Как узнать производительность видеокарты?

Tags: javascript

Существуют ли способы оценить производительность видеокарты, чтобы выставлять соответствующие настройки webGL-приложения? Использую blend4web.

К примеру, есть такой код, который узнает относительную плотность пикселей и на ее основе увеличивает разрешение Canvas:

```
var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

if ( devicePixelRatio > 1 ){
     m_config.set("canvas_resolution_factor", 2);
}
```

Но при этом, некоторые нетоповые android-девайсы или старые айфоны такие настройки могут не потянуть, FPS будет низким. В их случае лучше оставить `canvas_resolution_factor` как есть.

Проблема в том, что не известно, каким образом можно сделать оценки о производительности устройств.

Примерно тоже можно сказать про десктопы. На устройствах с хорошей видеокартой можно выставить дополнительные эффекты.

Comment: Можно попробовать прогнать тест на производительность и отталкиваться от его результатов. А можно сделать это настройкой, и пусть пользователь сам решает что для него приемлемо, а что - нет. Я, например, был бы весьма обескуражен, если бы какая-нибудь игра сама решала с каким "не совсем низким FPS" мне играть (а, вероятнее, страдать). И это не говоря уж о неточности тестов (неполная оценка и "сейчас работает так, а завтра - медленнее")

Comment: @Regent Да, я понимаю, когда настройка в играх, но представьте себе web-приложение, в которое пользователь зайдет, может быть один раз на несколько минут? Перегружать интерфейс дополнительными элементами управления, в котором и так нужно быстро разобраться?

Comment: Заставлять пользователя в обязательном порядке ковыряться в десятках настройках, у половины из которых непонятные названия, - это, конечно, не дело. Однако дать возможность желающим что-то поменять, на мой взгляд, стоит. А значения по умолчанию для настроек можно выбирать не исходя из тестов производительности, а такие, чтобы как можно меньшему количеству пользователей приходилось заходить в настройки. Я с подобными задачами не сталкивался, но сдаётся мне, что в JS в браузере ничего толком протестировать/определить в плане производительности не получится

Comment: Только если честный бенчмарк. У видеокарт много параметров, а нагрузки на них разного рода бывают.